# Finding the words' points in a crossword puzzle

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a 2D array of a crossword puzzle:

`0 1 2 3 4
0 t h i s q
1 m i l e u
2 a b y w i
3 n b y s c
4 l o o t k`

And given a list of words to find: this, quick, loot, mile, by, man

Objective: 
Find words in the puzzle in any direction (horizontal, vertical, diagonal)

Output:
Is to list all the points where the word is located.
for example, this: (0,0) , (0, 1), (0, 2), (0,3)

I'm having trouble getting started on this.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Try to solve the task by hand first and see how you personally handle this. Most of the time, this is a good start for a programmatic approach.

Comment: what I have so far is hard for me to explain but I'll try.

Comment: Sirko is right, how would you do it on paper ? You would first look for the first letter, then the second letter (in every direction) and then the third in the same direction as the scend, and so on.
Think about how to implement that then propose a basic algorithm to which we can point you in the right direction ;)

Comment: I tried doing it all in 1 method that returns an ArrayList of Points. The method I made temp ArrayList<Points> and two temp Strings that represents the word in the list I want to find and a String of words I get from the crossword puzzle. And then started doing a triple nested for loop. The first loop takes the first word for me to find. Second inner loop, is a # for my column then the third inner loop is a # for my rows. The third loop, I started adding up all the letters I get as I go along the board into one of the temp Strings, then check if that temp string has the word I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Might require some fixes but in general:

```
find_word(x,y,word,index,inc_x,inc_y):
  if x,y is not on board return false
  if letter[x,y] != word[index] return false
  if it is last letter return true
  call find_word(x+inc_x,y+inc_y,word,index+1,inc_x,inc_y)

foreach x:
    foreach y
        foreach word
            for x_inc in -1,0,1
               for y_inc in -1,0,1
                  if x_inc + y_inc == 0 continue
                  find_word(x,y,word,0,x_inc,y_inc)
```

If you want to make if faster than make a tree of words and you can remove cycle on words.
For example imagine you have: abc, aab, aac.

```
a
  a
    b
    c
  b
```

Now imagine you have found a letter a. 
Call find_word and get letter d for ex. There's no d in tree of a, so no word can be found. 
Call find_word and get letter a for ex. Now narrow search of words to subtree of a.

Thus you can go from w*h*num_words*max_length only to w*h*max_length.

Comment: Why would you specify an (x,y) position in the method? A systematic search should cover the whole board...

Comment: Because you need to start searching every word from every position. x,y specify current checking position.

Comment: Then start it from the origin and cover the whole board without needing to reinvoke the method on every square? :)

Comment: Doesn't that take too much time? To search up the whole board starting from the origin. Something with Big-O notation. @_@ I just made up that board. I could be given some other bigger board.

Comment: To find one word on the board you will need at most w*h*length operations. ( in reality much less ). 
To find n words: w*h*n*max_length.

Comment: @Evyione You could have a secondary code block that simply looks for the first letters of each 'clue' and then invoke this with that location as a start point, that'd cut down on search time considerably I guess

Comment: It looks like this would also "find" word-strings that are not in a straight direction, containing a veer, you know what i mean?

Comment: Psychemaster, that's the same code ) It won't change the time. This code actually looks for first letter and returns immediately if first letter doesn't match )

Comment: fast, yes, you're right. usually such tasks require to find words in any direction and veers also. but this code can be obviously adapted to horizontal, vertical, diagonal search only )